# How to reference Typescript module within nuxt.config

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, tsconfig

For dynamic route generation using Nuxt 2

nuxt.config

```
const { pairwiseTeams } = require('~/helpers/NFL/teams');

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  ...
  generate: {
    async routes() {
      return teamMatchups = pairwiseTeams.map(([teamA, teamB]) => `/nfl/matchups/${teamA}-${teamB}`);
    },
  },
```

helpers/NFL/teams.ts

```
export const pairwiseTeams = [['ARI', 'ATL'], ...]
```

Running `nuxt` yields `Cannot find module '~/helpers/NFL/teams'`

tsconfig.json does include

```
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
```

Comment: TS config paths are not magic. They don't make all your path aliases work everywhere. You should just resort to specifying the full relative path.

Comment: Yeah ./helpers/NFL/teams yields the same